# DataGridView Row Count always returns 1

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView2` within a panel in `tabcontrol1` as shown in the image below.

I have to calculate rows of grid view using

```
Dim rowCount = DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
```

or

```
Dim rowCount = DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
```

But using these methods, `rowCount` always equals `1`

Is this because the `DataGridView2` is in tabcontrol and a panel? If so, how do I calculate row count, or find the total number of rows of a DataGridView when it is within a tabcontrol or panel?

[image: View Of Form Having Grid within TabControl]

some code to show what i am doing

```
    Dim rowCount = DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1


        If rowCount = 0 Then
            DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = ItemName_TXT.Text
            DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = ItemQuantity_TXT.Text
 End If

           Dim j As Int32 = rowCount

        If j >= 1 Then
            DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value = ItemName_TXT.Text
            DataGridView2.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value = ItemQuantity_TXT.Text
         End If
```

Comment: Does `DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1` return 0, or 1? If there is no data in the DataGridView, you only have the one row (as shown in the image). As such, `DataGridView2.Rows.Count` should return 1, because there is only one row.

Comment: i have added data first time from textboxes as it returns 1  i used -1 to insert but even there is record it have to give 2 but gives only 1 every time

Comment: Are you saying you have two rows, and `DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1` returns 1? Because that's exactly what it should do (2-1=1!). I'd advise you test it with maybe 5 or 10 rows, let us know if you still get 1.

Comment: I TRIED AFTER FILL DATAGRID VIEW FROM DATABASE BUT IT RETURN 23 BUT WHEN I TRIED TO ADD ROWS FROM TEXTBOXES IT RETURN 1 FIRST TIME AND ROW ADDED 2ND TIME AGAIN RETURN 1 WHEN THERE IS ALREADY A ROW AND ROW DUPLICATED HOW TO ADD SECOND ROW

Comment: _I understand the problem much more clearly now, thanks to your effective use of the Caps Lock key._ So when you filled your DataGridView from a database, `DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1` returned 23? Did you expect a different result? How many rows were there?

Comment: i get answer check it

Comment: now how to remove current added row as i answered `DataGridView2.Rows.Add()`  suddenly after calling this

Comment: done `Me.DataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(rowCount)`

Answer (score -1):

```
    DataGridView2.Rows.Add()
        Dim rowCount = DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2
```

a new row added and gives exact calculation need by using -2